# How do we enter the command line prompt and initiate debugging in python when using pdb.set_trace() in a process running in background?

Tags: python-2.7, debugging, pdb

We are executing our process in the background. In the process we are using the pdb.set_trace() when a given condition is hit. My query is how do we enter the command line prompt and initiate debugging in this case.